# How to reduce the size of the emulator window?

Tags: swift, xcode7, emulation

I use **XCode 7.2** and after application run size of the emulator window is very big. 
[image: emulator window]

I make application for the iPhone 6s plus.
I unchecked **Use size classes** in **Main.storyboard**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulator Menu > Window > Scale

or

Command 1, 2, 3 or 4.

[image]